# (SSIS) Script Component "index was outside the bounds of the array"

Tags: ssis

I am using an SSIS (Visual Studio 2015) script component (C# 2015) to make a web request.  The response provides links to CSV files to be downloaded.  I use the links to stream the CSV files to outputs which I write to a SQL database in an OLEDB destination.  The CSV files are broken into 1000 rows.

I run this script once for each dataflow, one dataflow for each table, 12 dataflows in total.  Some work without issue, however some see this issue after loading some CSVs.

The error is

```
   at ScriptMain.CreateNewOutputRows()
   at UserComponent.PrimeOutput(Int32 Outputs, Int32[] OutputIDs, PipelineBuffer[] Buffers, OutputNameMap OutputMap)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.PrimeOutput(Int32 outputs, Int32[] outputIDs, PipelineBuffer[] buffers)
```

The script code is

```
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
    /*
      Add rows by calling the AddRow method on the member variable named "<Output Name>Buffer".
      For example, call MyOutputBuffer.AddRow() if your output was named "MyOutput".
    */
    var request = WebRequest.Create(Variables.urlparameter);
    request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    string responseText;
    string[] fileArray;
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();
        string responseCleaned = responseText.Substring(responseText.IndexOf('[') + 1, responseText.IndexOf(']') - responseText.IndexOf('[') - 1).Replace("\"", "");
        fileArray = responseCleaned.Split(',');
    }

    foreach (string file in fileArray)
    {
        HttpWebRequest fileReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(file);
        HttpWebResponse fileResp = (HttpWebResponse)fileReq.GetResponse();
        using (Stream fileStream = fileResp.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            string responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            string[] responseRows = responseString.Split(new string[] { "\"\r\n\"", "\"\n\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            foreach (string row in responseRows.Skip(1))
            {
                Output0Buffer.AddRow();
                string[] responseColumns = row.Split(new string[] { "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                Output0Buffer.caseid = responseColumns[0];
                Output0Buffer.assignedfrom = responseColumns[1];
                Output0Buffer.groupname = responseColumns[2];
                Output0Buffer.createdate = responseColumns[3];
                Output0Buffer.createday = responseColumns[4];
                Output0Buffer.audittype = responseColumns[5];
                Output0Buffer.minimpact = responseColumns[6];
                Output0Buffer.casetype = responseColumns[7];
                Output0Buffer.auditid = responseColumns[8];
                Output0Buffer.impact = responseColumns[9];
                Output0Buffer.cti = responseColumns[10];
                Output0Buffer.createhour = responseColumns[11];
                Output0Buffer.assignedtoindividual = responseColumns[12];
                Output0Buffer.closurecode = responseColumns[13];
                Output0Buffer.contacttime = responseColumns[14];
                Output0Buffer.impact12time = responseColumns[15];
                Output0Buffer.region = responseColumns[16];
                Output0Buffer.requesterlogin = responseColumns[17];
                Output0Buffer.resolution = responseColumns[18];
                Output0Buffer.resolvedby = responseColumns[19];
                Output0Buffer.resolveddate = responseColumns[20];
                Output0Buffer.rootcause = responseColumns[21];
                Output0Buffer.rootcausedetails = responseColumns[22];
                Output0Buffer.prioritylabel = responseColumns[23];
                Output0Buffer.ecd = responseColumns[24];
                Output0Buffer.dedupekey = responseColumns[25];
                Output0Buffer.groupmanagerlogin = responseColumns[26];
                Output0Buffer.assigneemanagerlogin = responseColumns[27];
                Output0Buffer.site = responseColumns[28];
                Output0Buffer.status = responseColumns[29];
                Output0Buffer.timespent = responseColumns[30];
                Output0Buffer.initialescalationtime = responseColumns[31];
                Output0Buffer.lastmodifieddate = responseColumns[32];
                Output0Buffer.totaltimespent = responseColumns[33];
                Output0Buffer.referenceinfo = responseColumns[34];
                Output0Buffer.shortdescriotion = responseColumns[35];
                Output0Buffer.cticategory = responseColumns[36];
                Output0Buffer.ctitype = responseColumns[37];
                Output0Buffer.ctiitem = responseColumns[38];
            }
        }
        fileReq = null;
        fileResp = null;
    }
}
```

And if it is useful, the JSON response I receive and use to call the web requests is:

```
{"files":["https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-0.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-1.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-2.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-3.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-4.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-5.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-6.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-7.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-8.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-9.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-10.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-11.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-12.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-13.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-14.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-15.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-16.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-17.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-18.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-19.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-20.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-21.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-22.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-23.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-24.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-25.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-26.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-27.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-28.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-29.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-30.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-31.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-32.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-33.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-34.csv","https://sample.url.com/raw/fetch/451cf3ecc1/raw-35.csv"],"info":["Defaulted to 'UTC' timezone"],"warn":["Truncated 'to' - dropped hours, minutes and seconds. Was 1469121708000, Used 1469059200000"]}
```

Comment: Put a break point in the script and step through the code in the debugger to get more information about what's going wrong.

Comment: I tried.  It generates the error after inserting a few hundred rows when adding an output column.  I was unable to find anything useful from it.  From what I can gather, this occurs when you try to create an output that does not exist, so the strange thing is that it does this after using the output multiple times.

On a side note, watches do not work in SSIS script components.  When I run this as its own VS package it runs fine but it also does not generate the outputs.

Comment: Ok then, what line of code does the error occur on?   What is value of the index at the time the error occurs, and what is the range of the array at the time?

Comment: I was unable to add a watch, however I added a try catch and rerouted the entire row anytime the catch was called.  It exported 2 rows which show the issue was the row I was processing not being properly split with the parameters I set.  Working on an updated split but it appears that for these select rows there was something I missed resulting in less columns than configured.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue was that the CSV line deliminator was \"\r\n\" and one of the columns had a value of \"\r\n\".  I updated it to [!,]\"\r\n\" which resolved the issue.

The index error was a result of the split not populating the array as much as I was expecting.  Thanks for taking a look, sorry for posting a question that was really just a mistake on my part.